# Syntax error while submitting pyspark job

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata

I have setup hadoop and spark on ubuntu 14 through VMware. I am trying to run python script of wordcount in spark/examples/... on standalone mode, but it's giving syntax error.

```
    ./bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --executor-memory  2g  usr/local/spark/examples/src/main/python/wordcount.py '/usr/local/spark/README.md'
     File "<stdin>", line 1
    ./bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --executor-memory 1g 
    /usr/local/spark/examples/src/main/python/wordcount.py '/usr/local/README.md'
        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am a beginner in spark, please tell me how to resolve it.....

Comment: Since the actual problem behind syntax errors is often on the line before the one indicated, please show a few of the previous lines. Also provide the full traceback.

Comment: This is the previous line...

Answer (score 0):

`wordcount.py` expects two inputs arguments, see [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/wordcount.py#L27)

Comment: what's the second argument

Comment: I mean input file as first argument but use of second argument is not specified, so what i have to pass on as second argument.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this error as i was calling ./bin/spark-submit from bin directory rather than Spark directory. It has nothing to deal with two arguments code works using single argument specifying file path.